# I don't know the right way to connect to my db in my login model, i'm using (oop - mysqli)

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, database-connection

i'm learning oop , i have those tow errors (mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\oop2\model\login.php on line 38 , : mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\oop2\model\login.php on line 40) and i don't know how the wright way to connect to my db in oop and mysqli.

database connect
database connect

```
class Database 
{
private $host;
private $user;
private $password;
private $database;

function __construct($filename)
{
    if(is_file($filename)) include $filename;
    else throw new Exception("Error!");

    $this->host     = $host;
    $this->user     = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->database = $database; 

    $this->connect();
}

public function connect()
{
    // connect to the server
    if(!mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user, $this->password,$this->database))
        throw new Exception("Error: not connected to the server.");        

}

function close()
{
    mysql_close();
}
}
```

login model

```
class Login{

private $username;
private $password;
private $cxn;

public function __construct($username,$password)
{
    $this->setData($username,$password);
    $this->connectToDb();
    $this->getData();
}

private function setData($username,$password)
{
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
}
private function connectToDb()
{
    include   '../model/database.php';
    $config = "../model/config.php";
    $this->cxn = new Database($config);
    $this->cxn->connect();

}

public function getData()
{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM admin
                 WHERE 
                 'username' = '$this->username' 
                 AND 
                 'password' = '$this->password'
                  ";
        $sql   = mysqli_query($this->cxn->connect(),$query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
        {
            return  TRUE;
        }

        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");

        }
}
public function close()
{
    $this->cxn->close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_connect` returns a link object representing the connection to the MySQL server. In your `Database` class you must save the return value of `mysqli_connect`:

```
class Database  {
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $connection; //Add this
```

Then:

```
public function connect() {

    if(!$this->connection) {
        // connect to the server
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user, $this->password,$this->database);
       //Do some error checking here !
    }
    return $this->connection;        

}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: connection in C:\wamp\www\oop2\model\database.php on line 26 ---- Cannot access empty property in C:\wamp\www\oop2\model\database.php on line 26

Comment: Yes, my bad Sorry!  just updated the answer, I forgot to remove the `$` sign ! `$this->$connection` to `$this->connection` !!!

Comment: ok it's solved now but i'm getting the error  of the Exception in login model

Comment: If you get "Error Processing Request" then maybe your query return an empty result !

Comment: how is that? my db admin table already has a username and password

Comment: Try to change your query to `"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE  username = '$this->username'  AND password = '$this->password' "` and make sure that the password is not encrypted !

Answer (score 0):

You must pass $host, $user, $password and $database to DataBase class like this.

```
class Login{

private $username;
private $password;
private $cxn;

public function __construct($username,$password)
{
    $this->setData($username,$password);
    $this->connectToDb();
    $this->getData();
}

private function setData($username,$password)
{
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
}
private function connectToDb()
{
    include   '../model/database.php';
    $config = "../model/config.php";
    $this->cxn = new Database($config, $host, $user, $password, $database);
    $this->cxn->connect();

}

public function getData()
{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM admin
                 WHERE 
                 'username' = '$this->username' 
                 AND 
                 'password' = '$this->password'
                  ";
        $sql   = mysqli_query($this->cxn->connect(),$query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
        {
            return  TRUE;
        }

        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");

        }
}
public function close()
{
    $this->cxn->close();
}

}
```

And change your Database class with this

```
class Database 
{
private $host;
private $user;
private $password;
private $database;

function __construct($filename, $host, $user, $password, $database)
{
    if(is_file($filename)) include $filename;
    else throw new Exception("Error!");

    $this->host     = $host;
    $this->user     = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->database = $database; 

    $this->connect();
}

public function connect()
{
    // connect to the server
    if(!mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user, $this->password,$this->database))
        throw new Exception("Error: not connected to the server.");        

}

function close()
{
    mysql_close();
}
}
```

Comment: He gets the values from a config file! This is not the real problem